# Regex to match a "PATH environment variable" like String

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to check if a String is formed as `NAME1=VALUE1;NAME2=VALUE2;`.

This is what I found so far :

```
s.matches("^(.+=.+;)*$")
```

But here's the tricky part: **the last semicolon is not mandatory**. So a string like `NAME1=VALUE1;NAME2=VALUE2` must be accepted.

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun not really. Firstly it'd be `?` and not `*`. Second the same expression is repeated and he wants only the last one to be optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression doesn't really do what it's expected to because of the greedy quantifier on one hand, and because you're using the dot which allows almost any character on the other hand.
This one should have the behavior you're expecting:

```
^(\w+=\w+;)*\w+=\w+;?$
```

Or, if an empty string is correct:

```
^(\w+=\w+;)*(\w+=\w+;?)?$
```

Note that I'm using \w just as an example of restriction.

Comment: You can simplify `(\w+=\w+;?)?` to `(\w+=\w+;)?`, since the optional `;` is covered by just making that term optional.

Comment: @Dukeling no, you're losing the fact that the `;` is optional if you're making that change.

Comment: My mistake, actually it's `(\w+=\w+;?)?` to `(\w+=\w+)?`. See [this](http://pastebin.com/Zcpe7ZxG) for a little proof.

Comment: @Dukeling this one is correct, yeah. Though it shouldn't change the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try that one:

```
^([^=]+=[^;]+;)*([^=]+=[^;]+;?)$
```

You also had some mistakes in your regexp since "." also matches "=". [^=] means "everything except the "="".

Comment: Thank you Chris. This one works for only 2 occurrences of `X=Y;` but won't work for a string like `"NAME1=VALUE1;NAME2=VALUE2;NAME3=VALUE3"`.

Comment: You need to put an asterisk in between the groups. (I edited the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Must it be a RegEx, could this do the job:

```
 for (String pair : myString.split(";")){
    if (! ((pair.indexOf("=") > 0) && (pair.indexOf("=") < pair.length()) &&   
          ((myString.split("=").length - myString.split(";").length) < 2) ))
      return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Comment: There might be a more optimized option for my issue, mixing the "check" with the "processing". Anyway, the code above does not work for a string like: `NAME1=VALUE1NAME2=VALUE2`.